# Issue with new Image() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code:

```
function CreateAndAnimateEnemyImg() {
  var enemy = new Image();
  enemy.src = 'enemy.jpg';
  enemy.class = 'Enemy';
  enemy.width = '30px';
  enemy.height = '30px';
  document.body.appendChild(enemy);
  enemy.onload = function () {
    alert('2. Image has fully loaded.');
    $('.Enemy').animate({ 'right': '+=20px' });
  }
}
$("#Start").click(function () {
  CreateAndAnimateEnemyImg();
});
```

The weird behavior is that the alert is raised but no image is shown, nor the animation is working. Any help please?

Comment: Why don't use `document.createElement` or `$('<img />')` instead?

Comment: can u give me an example ?

Comment: Set the `onload` before the `src`

Comment: You could use instead `var enemy = $('<img >')`  (implicit closing tag) and set src after onload handler for supporting older IE version with cached/broken image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code:

```
enemy.className = 'Enemy';
enemy.width = '30'; // no px needed
enemy.height = '30';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UqcqN/

You have two mistakes: if you set `width` property you don't have to provide units. And you should set `className` property instead of `class`.

It is also recommended to set `src` after `onload` handler.

Comment: I think it is OP's issue

Comment: Yes, it is, the image is there but the width and height are 0

Answer (score 0):

You have to `enemy.src = 'enemy.jpg';` AFTER you define: `enemy.onload`.

Comment: Apparently, onload handler is fired already for OP but ya, this is better to do it like this

Answer (score 0):

i think no need for giving string kind of 'px'; 
rtefer this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_img_height

here is the complete demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpYdt/1/)

```
function CreateAndAnimateEnemyImg() {
  var enemy = new Image();
  enemy.src = 'http://media.steampowered.com/apps/440/icons/icon_dueling_large.14fd9f2da0f24b2dfaac37d1600c821ddb6d3456.png';
  enemy.class = 'Enemy';
  enemy.width = '130';
  enemy.height = '130';
  document.body.appendChild(enemy);
  enemy.onload = function () {
    alert('2. Image has fully loaded.');
      $('.Enemy').html(enemy);
      console.log(enemy);
    $('.Enemy').animate({ 'right': '+=20px' });
  }
}
$("#Start").click(function () {
  CreateAndAnimateEnemyImg();
});
```